# Django: Database used for prefetch_related is not the same that the parent query

Tags: python, django, orm, database-replication

I'm using a multi-db in my Django app with a master database and a read replica, but to avoid replication lag problems the router always uses default database except few places where I set DB manually.

I'm facing an issue as I don't know how to specify the database used for prefetch_related.

For example I want the next query to use only `read_replica` DB, but it does 2 queries, the first goes to `read_replica` as expected and the second goes to `default` DB.

```
users = UserProfile.objects.using('read_replica').prefetch_related('usermedia_set').filter(id__in=user_ids)
```

This are the output of this query:

> SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
>
> SELECT VERSION(); args=None
>
> SELECT ... FROM `ftmanager_userprofile` WHERE (`ftmanager_userprofile`.`id` IN (33); args=(33,)
>
> SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL; args=None
>
> SELECT VERSION(); args=None
>
> SELECT ... FROM `ftmanager_usermedia` WHERE `ftmanager_usermedia`.`user_id` IN (33); args=(33,)

I see a related ticket on [Django tickets](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17696) but I do not understand how to apply `using()` to inner queryset.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution thinking about the Django ticket, you need to use the`Prefetch` class to define the inner queryset used by prefetch_related, it really messes the code but the gain deserves it:

```
from django.db.models.query import Prefetch
users = UserProfile.objects.using('read_replica').prefetch_related(Prefetch('usermedia_set', queryset=UserMedia.objects.using('read_replica'))).filter(id__in=user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. Configuring the router (namely, db_for_read and using instance from hints) helped:

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    instance = hints.get('instance')
    if instance is not None:
        if instance._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return self.route_db_name 
    elif model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return self.route_db_name
```