# How to get model data to appear as a field in another model's response

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views

These are simplified versions of my models (the user model is just an id and name)

```
class Convo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='convo_owner')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Convo_user')

class Convo_user (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    convo = models.ForeignKey(Convo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    convo = models.ForeignKey(Convo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my view

```
class ConvoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = serializers.ConvoSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return None

def list(self, request):
    curr_user = request.user.id

    # Collecting the list of conversations
    conversations = models.Conversation.object.filter(ConvoUser__user_id=request.user.id)
    #Getting list of conversation id's
    conv_ids = list(conversations.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))
    #Getting list of relevant comments
    comments = models.Comments.objects.filter(conversation_id__in=conv_ids)

    return Response(self.get_serializer(conversations, many=True).data)
```

And my current serializer

```
class ConvoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""A serializer for messaging objects"""
# access = AccessSerializer(many=True)

    # model = models.Comments
    # fields = ('id', 'name', 'content', 'convo_id')

class Meta:
    model = models.Convo
    fields = ('id', 'owner_id')
```

The current response I get is of the form

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "owner_id": 32
    }, ...
]
```

But I would like to add a comments field that shows all the properties of comments into the response, so basically everything in the second queryset (called comments) and I'm not sure how to go about this at all. (I retrieve the comments in the way I do because I'm trying to minimize the calls to the database). Would I need to create a new view for comments, make its own serializer and then somehow combine them into the serializer for the convo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No data appears because my serializers are using the default database, not sure why but a step forward

EDIT:

[Django: Database used for prefetch_related is not the same that the parent query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139674/django-database-used-for-prefetch-related-is-not-the-same-that-the-parent-query) Provided me the correct answer, I was able to choose the database with this method because for some reason inner queries use the default DB

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set up your models, you can access the comments of each `Convo` through Django's ORM by using [`convo_object.comments_set.all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), so you could set up your `ConvoSerializer` to access that instance's comments, like this:

```
class ConvoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""A serializer for messaging objects"""

    comments_set = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
       model = models.Convo
       fields = ('id', 'owner_id', 'comments_set')
```

and then you define your `CommentSerializer` like:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = models.Comments
       fields = ('id', 'name', 'content')
```

Comment: I saw the use of the set.all() method before but I'm not sure how to actually use it to retrieve the information in my viewset in addition to what I already have. (Just doing above adds the field with no data in it as expected?)

Comment: the way i structured it, just by passing the `Convo` objects to the serializer it would already use the `CommentSerializer` in all the comments objects of each `Convo`.

Comment: Just updating the conversation serializer and adding the comment serializer added a field comments_set with an empty array, is there something I am missing?

Comment: even for conversations that have comments?

Comment: Yes it's empty for all conversations, though maybe this requires a different post as the initial question was technically solved?